# UI Datepicker setting to UTC Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, uidatepicker, utc

I know this question may have been asked before, but I dont really get how to solve it.
Basically what happens it, that the Datepicker shows a different date than the input field as the datepicker seems to ignore the UTC and only sees the local time. 
[image]

However when I submit the form, it sends the correct UTC date.

```
<button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default datepickerButton dateButton"
                            datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                            ng-click="clickCalendar($event,$index,0)"
                            ng-model="first.date"
                            is-open="first.open"
                            ng-change="selectDate($index)"
                            show-weeks="false"
                            min-date="Datepicker.getMinDate()"
                            max-date="Datepicker.getMaxDate()"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                            show-button-bar="false"
                        >{{first.date|changeDateFormat}}
                    </button>
```

and the filter:

```
     .filter('changeDateFormat',function($translate){
    return function(date) {
      if(date===undefined){
      return date;
      }else {
        var day = date.getUTCDate();
        var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
        if(day<10) day = "0" + day;
        if(month<10) month = "0" + month;
        if ($translate.use() === 'en_US') {
          return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        } else if ($translate.use() === 'de') {
          return day + "." + month + "." + year;
        } else {
          return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

However, when I submit the form, this datepicker it embedded in, it sends the correct UTC date of 31st of January and not the 30th.
How can I make sure, that the datepicker (view) itself also has the UTC date instead of the local date?

Contact me, if you need further explanation and if this doesn't get clear.

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap Datepicker